# CLOSURE COMPILER

Tags: logging, compiler-construction, closures

i want to copy the errors in command prompt to a txt file .to output the compiled code to a file ,we use --js_output_file abc.js .How to do the same for logging errors.Thanks in advance

Comment: you could do with saying what opertaing system ou are using

Comment: i am using windows 7 .and want do this using command prompt .

Answer (score 0):

You can use closrecomplier.exe --js_output_file abc.js >errors.log

Comment: it 's not logging the errors .it still outputs the compiled code in the abc.js file. can we set the ouput-format to errors .Do we have a commandline argument fo that

Comment: command >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt  => stout will have the compiled code and stderr will have the error log